# Attaching to a service in screen

Tags: gnu-screen

I am fairly new to Ubuntu, but I am becoming better everyday. I know that to detach from a service in screen you do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>+<kbd>d</kbd>. But I do not know how to attach back to it when I need to.

Can someone tell me what the command is to attach back to running screen services?

Comment: Where did you learn how to detach from a session? I'd expect it to also explain how to reattach.

Answer (score 1):

If you need information on how to use a certain command, check out the corresponding man page. For screen, simply type `man screen` in terminal. Also, for some programs more detailed information, often complete manuals, can be found on the info pages (in this case: `info screen`). The screen man page gives the answer to your question:

```
screen -r
```

If you need to know which sessions are running, run `screen -ls`. Then you can reattach with `screen -r <pid.tty.host>`, where pid.tty.host is given by `screen -ls`.